# Vue Axios API objects to array of objects

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, currency

I'm currently having issues with displaying data of currencies on my website, where I want to display the short name for a currency, and the value of the currency.

I'm using this api, with USD as the base: https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD

The code I have running and getting me the data is:

```js
getCurrencies() {
  axios
    .get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD")
    .then(response => {
      this.currencies = response.data.rates;
      console.log(this.currencies);
    });
}
```

The output I'm getting is simply the value of the currency of course, and I'm looking for a way to break these objects into arrays of objects where I could call for ex:
currency.short & currency.price

This way I'll have both the short name and the price displayed seperately on the website, rather than just having the currency value displayed when I use "response.data.rates"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Object.keys` method to iterate through the rates and the `map` function to create your objects, just like this:

```js
this.currencies = Object.keys(response.data.rates).map(k => ({
    short: k,
    price: response.data.rates[k]
}))
```

Comment: Nice thanks it worked, I tried this method a little earlier, but it didn't seem to work

Comment: Sometimes Javascript stops working for a while, you just need to wait for it to work again :)